# Wrap a div around every four divs

Tags: php, opencart

I need a little help with a php loop for OpenCart.

I need to do is wrap a div around the output of the data every 4 loops.

I have the following

```
<?php foreach ($categories as $category) { ?>
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3">.....</div>
<?php } ?>
```

**I get this**

```
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3">.....</div>
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3">.....</div>
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3">.....</div>
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3">.....</div>
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3">.....</div>
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3">.....</div>
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3">.....</div>
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3">.....</div>
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3">.....</div>
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3">.....</div>
```

**But what I'm hoping to get is**

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3">.....</div>
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3">.....</div>
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3">.....</div>
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3">.....</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3">.....</div>
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3">.....</div>
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3">.....</div>
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3">.....</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3">.....</div>
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3">.....</div>    
</div>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Hint: make a research over `%` (modulus) operator.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

try this

```
<?php 
$i=0;
$wrap_count = 4; // you can change this no of divs to wrap
foreach ($categories as $category) 
{ 
    $i+=1;
    if($i%$wrap_count==1)
    {
        echo '<div class="row">';
    }
?>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3">.....</div>
<?php 
    if($i%$wrap_count==0)
    {
        echo '</div>';
    }
} 

if($i%$wrap_count!=0)
{
    echo '</div>';
}
?>
```

Comment: it is working. but, Here, Available 10 categories now. So I get this now `<div class"row">1,2,3,4</div>` and `<div class"row">5,6,7,8,9,10</div>` but, I want to this `<div class"row">1,2,3,4</div>` and `<div class"row">5,6,7,8</div>` and `<div class"row">9,10</div>`

Comment: According to your code 6 categories wrap in last div. but, i want to 4 categories warp in every div. So, I think, Here, should be 2 categories wrap in last div.

Comment: check once again it is tested last div will contains only 2 if you have 10 categories see https://eval.in/174828

Comment: I have check again. but, it is not working in my code. 6 categories wrap in last div.

Answer (score 4):

```
<?php

$i = 0;
foreach ($categories as $category) {

  if (($i % 4) === 0) {
    echo "<div class='row'>";
  }

  echo '<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3"></div>';

  if (($i % 4) === 3) {
    echo "</div>";
  }

  $i++;
}

?>
```

---

Ps, If `$categories` is a non keyed array, ie `array('a', 'b', 'c')` then you can get rid of the `i = 0;` and `i++;` and change the foreach to `foreach ($categories as $i => $category) {`

---

And as zerkms mentioned in a comment, the magic here is coming from [% (Modulo operation)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation), which is essentially like a clock- the numbers will increment from 0 upwards until they hit 12, at which point it is reset to 0 again. So the clock is said to be modulo twelve. In this instance we're using modulo four to cyclically print our our opening and closing row elements.

Modulo four would be the sequence `0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, etc`

Answer (score 3):

Try this :-

```
<div class="row">
    <?php
    $i = 1;
   foreach ($categories as $category) { ?>

      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3">.....</div>

    <?php if ($i % 4 == 0){ ?>
    </div><div class="row">
    <?php } ?>
    <?php $i++; ?>
    <?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use a counter variable. Initially set it to equal 0. Then for each loop check its value. If it is equal to 0 then output `<div class="row">` and add 1 to the variable's value. If its value is > 0 and < 5 then output `<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3">.....</div>` and add 1 to it's value. If it is  equal to 5 output `</div>` and reset the counter variable to 0.

Something like (code tested):

```
<?php
    $counter = 0;
    foreach ($categories as $category) {
                If ($counter == 0) {
                    echo '<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3">.....</div>
';
    $counter++;
                } elseif ($counter > 0 && $counter < 3) {
                    echo '<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3">.....</div>
';
    $counter++;
                } elseif ($counter == 3) {
                    echo '<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3">.....</div>
</div>
';
                    $counter = 0;
                }
    }
    if ($counter > 0) {
                echo '</div>
';
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

The Modulo operator will be equal to zero when used in a comparison with the number of items you would like in a row. So you can output your starting `<div>` there.

To add a closing div you will need to check the modulo of 4 is equal to 3 or if we have reached the total number of items, to prevent a missing close `</div>`.

```
<?php 

    // set a counter
    $rowCount = 0;

    // store the total number of categories minus 1 as we will be
    // counting from 0 with the counter

    $categoryTotal = count($categories) - 1;

    foreach($categories as $c){

        if($rowCount % 4 == 0){
            echo '<div class="row">';
        }?>

        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3""></div>

        <?php 

        // add your closing div if it is the end of a row or if there are no more items    

        if($rowCount % 4 == 3 || $rowCount == $categoryTotal){
            echo '</div>';
        }

        // increment your counter
        $rowCount++;

    } ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have an alternative option that might work depending on your array.

```
$new_array = array_chunk($your_array, 4);

foreach($new_array as $group_of_$four){
  echo '<div class="row">';
  foreach($group_of_four as $one){
     // Single Item
  }
  echo '</div>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, add this to your code:

```
//before foreach
$i = 0;
```

// inside the foreach before its closing }

```
$i++;
}//this closes the foreach
```

And then before adding any div (probably in the beginning of the foreach:

```
if($i % 4 == 0)
{
 echo "<div class='each-four-iterations'>";
}
```

And before the $i++ statement, add this :

```
if($i % 4 == 0)
{
 echo "</div>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$wrap_count = 2; // you can change this no of divs to wrap
foreach ($categories as $category) :
$i+=1;
if($i%$wrap_count==1):
echo '<div class="row">';
endif;?>
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3">.....</div>
if($i%$wrap_count==0) : echo '</div>'; endif; endforeach;
?>
```

Works Fine For me

Answer (score 0):

Try this one. It works for me.

```
<?php $count = 1; ?>
                <?php foreach ($model->userProfile->portfolio as $item): ?>
                    <?php if ($count % 4 == 1): ?>
                        <div class="row" style="margin-bottom: 30px;">
                    <?php endif ?>

                        <div class="col-md-3">

                        </div>

                    <?php if ($count % 4 == 0): ?>

                        </div>

                    <?php endif ?>

                    <?php  $count++ ?>
                <?php endforeach ?>
```