# Add div after 5 item in sequence

Tags: php

I need to add a div tag after each 5 items. can any one provide any assistance with this logic, i have tried but, no success.

I have this code:

```
<div class="product-grid">
    <?php foreach ($products as $product) { ?>
    <div class="item">.....</div>
    <?php } ?>
  </div>
```

**I get this**

```
<div class="product-grid">
    <div class="item">.....</div>
    <div class="item">.....</div>
    <div class="item">.....</div>
    <div class="item">.....</div>
    <div class="item">.....</div>
    <div class="item">.....</div>
    <div class="item">.....</div>
    <div class="item">.....</div>
    <div class="item">.....</div>
    <div class="item">.....</div>
    <div class="item">.....</div>
 </div>
```

**It would look like this:** (add a div after 5 item in sequence.)

```
<div class="product-grid">
    <div class="item">.....</div>
    <div class="item">.....</div>
    <div class="item">.....</div>
    <div class="item">.....</div>
    <div class="item">.....</div>
    <div class="clearfix visible-xs-block"></div>
    <div class="item">.....</div>
    <div class="item">.....</div>
    <div class="item">.....</div>
    <div class="item">.....</div>
    <div class="item">.....</div>
    <div class="clearfix visible-xs-block"></div>
    <div class="item">.....</div>
 </div>
```

Some help would be appreciated.

Comment: put a counter inside the loop and if the counter is dividable with 6, add the required div, or else add the normal div.

Comment: please check :- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25093916/wrap-a-div-around-every-four-divs/25094096#25094096

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<?php 
// control variable 
$counter = 0;
?>
<div class="product-grid">
    <?php foreach ($products as $product) { ?>
        <div class="item">.....</div>
        <?php 
        // on every #5 result
        if(++$counter % 5 === 0) { ?>
          <div class="clearfix visible-xs-block"></div>
        <?php  
        }
    } 
    ?>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the MOD operator:

```
<div class="product-grid">
    <?php
        $i = 0;
        foreach ($products as $product) {
            $i++;
            if($i % 5 == 0){
    ?>
                <div class="clearfix visible-xs-block"></div>
    <? } ?>
        <div class="item">.....</div>
    <?php } ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since, it's every sixth item getting that particular class, you can use a temporary counter to keep track:

```
<div class="product-grid">
    <?php
      $i = 1;
      foreach ($products as $product) {
        if( $i % 6 != 0 ) {
    ?>
    <div class="item">.....</div>
    <?php
        }
        else {
    ?>
    <div class="clearfix visible-xs-block"></div>
    <?php
        }
        $i++;
      }
    ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
You can do it like this:

<div class="product-grid">
   <?php
        $i = 1;
        foreach ($products as $product) {
            echo '<div class="item">.....</div>';
          if($i%5 == 0){
              echo '<div class="clearfix visible-xs-block"></div>';
          }  
          $i++;
        }
   ?> 
</div>
```